# Spacing between equation and text

Tags: spacing

How do I create a space for this statement:

[image]

I want to have some space between less than 0 and the for $x^{*} \neq$.

This the code that I'm using:

```
Lastly, the comparative static of $x^*$ w.r.t $\bar{P}$, $$\pdi{x^*}{\bar{P}}=-\frac{-1 - \frac{-a}{2(x^{*}-1)}}{\underbrace{\pdi{U^{c}}{x}-\pdi{U^{h}}{x}}_\text{(-) by stability condition}}\eqs{-1 - \frac{-a}{2(x^{*}-1)}} < 0 \text{for $x^{*}\neq 1$}.$$
```

Comment: include the space within the `\text{...}`.  often `\qquad` is used (works in either math or text).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically one would include the space as part of your `\text`, insert a manual control space `\` , or use a `\quad`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1 / \partial #2}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\overset{s}{=}}

\begin{document}
Lastly, the comparative static of $x^*$ w.r.t.\ $\bar{P}$,
\[
  \pdi{x^*}{\bar{P}} = -\frac{-1 - \frac{-a}{2(x^*-1)}}{\underbrace{\pdi{U^c}{x}-\pdi{U^h}{x}}_{\mathclap{\text{($-$) by stability condition}}}}
    \eqs{-1 - \frac{-a}{2(x^{*}-1)}} < 0 \text{ for $x^{*} \neq 1$}.
\]

Lastly, the comparative static of $x^*$ w.r.t.\ $\bar{P}$,
\[
  \pdi{x^*}{\bar{P}} = -\frac{-1 - \frac{-a}{2(x^*-1)}}{\underbrace{\pdi{U^c}{x}-\pdi{U^h}{x}}_{\mathclap{\text{($-$) by stability condition}}}}
    \eqs{-1 - \frac{-a}{2(x^{*}-1)}} < 0 \ \text{for $x^{*} \neq 1$}.
\]

Lastly, the comparative static of $x^*$ w.r.t.\ $\bar{P}$,
\[
  \pdi{x^*}{\bar{P}} = -\frac{-1 - \frac{-a}{2(x^*-1)}}{\underbrace{\pdi{U^c}{x}-\pdi{U^h}{x}}_{\mathclap{\text{($-$) by stability condition}}}}
    \eqs{-1 - \frac{-a}{2(x^{*}-1)}} < 0 \quad \text{for $x^{*} \neq 1$}.
\]

\end{document}
```

Above I loaded [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) (which automatically loads [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)). It allowed me to use `\mathclap` for the `\underbrace` text - avoiding possible overflow of the denominator in the fraction.

Note the use of [`\[`...`\]` rather than `$$`...`$$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764).

Comment: I'd write `$-$` for the term in the underbrace material, and I'd use `\dfrac` for the fractional expression in the numerator of the first big fraction.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks. I've added one suggestion... the last may be subjective in terms of its use.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `\;\text{for ...}` instead of `\ \text{for ...}`?

Comment: @KevinC: ``\  `` is a regular inter-word space, the same you'll use when you type `$...$ blah blah blah`. So, I'd prefer that above `\,`, `\;` or `\:`. I might spring for `\quad`, but just as long as one is consistent in your usage.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\,` to insert a thin space (looks better than `\quad` or `\qquad`)